# Can i redirect a Subdomain to another DNS with Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, router, cloudflare

i changed for my domain the dns to cloudflare.
is it possible after all the dns stuff gets now handled by cloudflare that i make one subdomain where i say that another dns should solve the naming?

in my case i my provider have a dynamic dns service i use with my router i called router.mydomain.tld. on the side from the provider the router syncs and i can see the ip but cloudflare don't know about that.

i tried to set for this domain a NS Record in which i set

`NS router provider.dns.tld``

but i still don't get any response.
i know there is a way to setup a cronjob and update the url via cloudflare api directly but i not wanted to avoid setting up a machine for that task since my home router have already the dyndns stuff working.

is it possible to get this done with cloudflare and when yes how to set it up.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delegate one subdomain to resolve the DNS of another, you should use a CNAME record to point that record for another.

If you want to perform a HTTP redirect from one DNS record to another, you can use a [Forwarding Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-) to do this.

Comment: thanks for the tip. the problem is that the ip is a dynamic ip of my router so its changing. i gave up my first solution and wrote used the cloudflare api to do the task via bash script. i will clean things up and publish it later on in a docker container for others ... i will post the link here when done.